# Adding class dynamically from template

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am trying to add a class to an Item depending on whether or not this same class exist in another Item.

In the following code, I used data binding with `classList` but it didn't work:

```html
<ion-item #firstItem>
   <ion-label>My label</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="text" formControlName="myInput"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<!-- ....... -->
<ion-item [class.myClass]="firstItem.classList.contains('myClass')">
  <ion-input value="myValue" readonly></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

My goal is whenever the `firstItem` has the class `myClass`, it will be added automatically to the second item, but all I've got is an **undefined** `classList`

Do you have any idea why my previous code isn't working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `#firstItem` variable refers to the `ion-item` component instance, not to the underlying HTML element. The component class does not have the `classList` property.

You can access the `ion-item` HTML element in code with the `ViewChild` `read` option, and check if the class is defined for that element in a method:

```
@ViewChild("firstItem", { read: ElementRef }) firstItemRef: ElementRef;

public firstItemHasClass(className: string): boolean {
  return this.firstItemRef.nativeElement.classList.contains(className);
}
```

The method is then called in the template:

```
<ion-item [class.myClass]="firstItemHasClass('myClass')">
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ion-item-tag-tvcxbc?file=pages%2Fcontact%2Fcontact.html) for a demo.